# Compare tables Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have two tables. Contract and Schoolstudent. And I have two custom filters. When I choose the Registered filter, my query returns the correct rows. But when I choose the Unregistered filter, I want to return the Unregistered students. Now it returns all the Students. My query is like this:

```
if ($this->filter=='R'){
  $criteria->addBetweenCondition('contractdate',$from, $to, 'AND');
}
else {
  $criteria->addBetweenCondition('schoolstudents.createddate',$from, $to, 'AND');
}
```

So when I choose 'R', it searches correctly between the `contractdate` and it returns the results I want. When I choose the other option, how can I compare between the two tables and return only the unregistered students? Essentially, now my query either returns the registered students or all of them.

Comment: can you add the entire `cdbcriteria` code ?

Comment: I posted the solution. I think it works! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I think I figured it out! I changed my code to this:

```
 if ($this->filter=='R'){
      $criteria->addBetweenCondition('contractdate',$from, $to, 'AND');
}
else {
    $criteria2 = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria2->with = 'contracts';
    $criteria2->condition = 'contractdate IS NULL';
    $criteria->addBetweenCondition('schoolstudents.createddate',$from, $to, 'AND');
    $criteria->mergeWith($criteria2);//for filtering based on unregistered students
```